# Alertmanager webex integration

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, webex

I am trying to integrate Alertmanager to Webex to receive alerts in channel.
For that purpose I was trying webhook_configs. Also I can see webex_configs in https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webex_config

But using webex_configs  prometheus operator throws error "unmarshal errors:\n  line 32: field webex_configs not found in type config.plain"

Is there any way to solve this ? Anyone of you have tried can you please help me with some example.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
    {
        "name": "The team",
        "webex_configs": [
            {
                "send_resolved": true,
                "api_url": "https://webexapis.com/v1/messages",
                "room_id": "<our room id>",
                "http_config": {
                    "tls_config": {
                        "insecure_skip_verify": true
                    },
                    "proxy_url": "<our http proxy>",
                    "authorization": {
                        "type": "Bearer",
                        "credentials": "<bot access token>"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```